# Nginx Location and URI matching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx

I am trying to run use nginx as reverse proxy, but having problems with URI matching

Application_1  running on 8080
Application_2 running on 8181

/api/v1/sql url be directed to Application_1
/api/v1/map and /tiles url be directed to Application_2

and the rest of the url to the rails application. Below is my attempt of the nginx config, but i think there is an error with Application_2 matching.

```
    upstream application_1{
            server  127.0.0.1:8080;
    }

    upstream application_2{
            server  127.0.0.1:8181;
    }


    location ^~  /api/v1/sql/ {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://application_1;
            break;
            error_page  404 = /;
    }



    location ^~ (/api/v1/map/ | /tiles) {
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://application_2;
            break;
            error_page  404 = /;
    }

    location / {

        if ($http_origin) {
                add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
                add_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods "GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT";
                add_header         Access-Control-Allow-Headers   Content-Type;
                add_header         Access-Control-Max-Age         86400;
        }
       passenger_spawn_method direct;
       root    /var/www/html ;
       passenger_enabled on;            
       rails_env development;
   }
```

When i try to post like http://mywebsite.com/api/v1/map?q=abcd i get status message "301 Moved Permanently" but when i access from the application directly http://mywebsite.com:8181/api/v1/map?q=abcd. it works ok.

Also, http://mywebsite.com/api/v1/maps has to be served by rails instead of application_2

Can anyone help me with correct nginx locatin configuration?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is related to having `/` at the end of location definition.

You are requesting `/api/v1/map?q=abcd` and in your config you have `/api/v1/map**/**` (with the trailing `/`) 
Nginx tries to 301 redirect  your `/api/v1/map` request to `/api/v1/map**/**` (because it has it configured with `/` at the end) , right?

I would recommned configuring your locations:

```
location ^~ /api/v1/sql
location ^~ /api/v1/map
```

`^~` in nginx means match locations starting with and has a high priority. This way even your `/api/v1/maps` uri should be matching OK.

Hope it helps.